# How to add NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER to Administrator Group via Command-line or through a database operation?

Tags: administrator

For some specific purpose , I need to add NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER account to Administrator Group . It can be done through Computer Management->Local Users and Groups->Groups . 
However I need to get this done through a piece of code in Java . Is there a way to get this done through command-line or executing some procedure on the database ?

Comment: `C:\>net localgroup /?`

Comment: I tried out this :

net localgroup administrator /add "NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER "

It throws the error :  There is no such global user or group

Comment: However I am able to add it manually navigating through Computer Management and that solves the purpose .

Comment: Can you explain what specific purpose that would be? Maybe your time and energy should go into fixing this instead. The database service account should probably not be a computer administrator.

Comment: @Tomalak I had replaced the LocalSystem account for MSSQLSERVER and SQL Server Agent by : NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER and NT SERVICE\SQL Server Agent  respectively . Now when I execute the statement  : EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_servicecontrol 'START' , 'sqlserveragent' . it throws the error 'Access Denied' . When I add the account to the Administrator group manually , this gets resolved .

Comment: So I wanted to add NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER to Administrator Group . But was looking for a way to get this done through code instead of doing it manually

Comment: But the system should start services, you should not do it from inside SQL server. Simply set the Sql Server Agent service to auto start in the service manager.

Comment: @Tomalak : Appreciate you suggestion! But I am stuck with a circumstance where I need to check if the service is up , and start it through a piece of code is it's not , then follow it up with a subsequent procedure . Just wondering if there is a way to do it.

Comment: I actually figured out the way . The below syntax successfully adds it :

net localgroup administrator NT" "SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER /add

Comment: But anyways this will weaken the security so I will be using some other way to get it done . The purpose of my question was just to figure out if this can be done .

Comment: Thanks everyone for the responses/suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

```
net localgroup Administrators /add "NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER"
```

From an admin cmd window